# Composite Attributes feature requires Xcode 15.0 model file format or later

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use new feature from CoreData called Composite attributes, but when I'm adding composite attribute to existing model file or creating new project with CoreData and composite attribute I see error **Composite Attributes feature requires Xcode 15.0 model file format or later**. Minimum tools version for Core Data model file is Xcode 11.0, I can't choose Xcode 15 there.

reproduced on Xcode 15 beta 1 and Xcode 15 beta 2.

how to change model file format to use this new feature?